# Java error: method recordShot in class PaintballPlayer cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: java

When I compile my code I get this error:

"PaintballPlayerTest.java:19: error: method recordShot in class PaintballPlayer cannot be applied to given types;
sheldon.recordShot(0);
       ^
  required: no arguments
  found: int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length"

It has been quite frustrating and I was hoping if someone here might be able to help me out. The code is as follows....

Mine:

```
import java.util.*;

public class PaintballPlayer
{
private String firstName, middleName, lastName;
private String secFirst, secLast;
private int id;
private int count;
private static int totalPlayers;
private int playerID;
private int players;
private int shots;
private static int shotsFired;


public PaintballPlayer(String first, String middle, String last)
{
    count = 0;
    id = totalPlayers++;
    players = count++;
    shots = count++;
    firstName = first;
    middleName = middle;
    lastName = last;

}

public PaintballPlayer(String f, String l)
{
    this (f,"",l);
    id = count++;

}


   public PaintballPlayer() 
{
totalPlayers++;
    }


   public static int getTotalPlayers() 
{
return totalPlayers;
}

public int recordShot()
{
    return count;
}

public String toString()
{
    String name;
    String n;
    name = firstName + " " + middleName + " " + lastName;

    return name;

}


public int getPlayerID()
{
    playerID = count;
    return playerID;
}

}
```

Test Code:

```
public class PaintballPlayerTest
{

public static void main (String [] args)
{
//Part 1 check constructor & toString --(make sure ID is working too)
PaintballPlayer sheldon = new PaintballPlayer ("Sheldon", "Lee", "Cooper");
PaintballPlayer leonard = new PaintballPlayer ("Leonard", "Hofstadter");
PaintballPlayer amy = new PaintballPlayer ("Amy", "Farrah", "Fowler");

System.out.println(sheldon);
System.out.println(leonard);

//Part 2 test getTotalPlayer --should be 3
System.out.println("The team has this many players " + PaintballPlayer.getTotalPlayers());

//Part 3 test recordShot
sheldon.recordShot(0);
sheldon.recordShot(1);
leonard.recordShot(0);
leonard.recordShot(0);
sheldon.recordShot(0);
sheldon.recordShot(1);
leonard.recordShot(2);
}
```

My problem lies in the area labeled part 3. I appreciate any help that I get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> required: no arguments found: int reason: actual and formal argument
>   lists differ in length"

Exception message is pretty much clear.

You have `recordShot()` without parameter in `PaintballPlayer`

```
public int recordShot()
{
    return count;
}
```

But calling with `int` parameter in `PaintballPlayerTest`

```
sheldon.recordShot(0);
```

Either you need to change `recordShot()` to `recordShot(int cnt)` (or) remove passing value while calling `recordShot()`

Comment: So with this, would I add "int" inside of the parenthesis? `public int recordShot(something here)` EDIT: I think I see what you mean

Comment: @DevonFreese: I couldn't quite understand what you are trying to achieve with recordShot()? you are just returning count there, then why you need to pass parameter?

Comment: It is to record how many shots are fired so that I can generate an average and score at some other point in the code. What you suggest worked very well.

Comment: @DevonFreese: But in your code you are not record (saving/assigning) that number to any other variable right? May be you need to increase the count with new number being passed, is that what you want to do?